# Angular HTTP - Subscribe gives unresolved variable

Tags: angular, typescript

I have an APIService class with the next method:

```
  public getRecipeIndex() : Observable<Recipe[]>
  {
    return this.http.get<Recipe[]>(this.serverURL+'recipes');
  }
```

I'm calling this method in component

```
  ngOnInit() {
    this.api.getRecipeIndex()
        .subscribe(
            resp => this.recipes = resp.data
        );
  }
```

and I have an error on `resp.data' - unresolved variable data`.

All API responses have 'data' property. 
The basic response structure from API is `'data' => [...]`.
How can I solve this problem? I hope I can create some basic type to annotate all API calls.

Comment: You are typing it as Recipe[], shouldn't the return type be {data: Recipe[] } then?

Comment: @DavidSherman no way. As I've mentioned, response structure is 

`data => []`. So, the Recipe[] type is resp.data

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I've created a separate APIResponse to annotate response data from HTTP and then map data to Recipe[].

```
  public getRecipeIndex() : Observable<Recipe[]>
  {
    return this.http.get<APIResponse>(this.serverURL+'recipes')
        .pipe(
            map(response => response.data)
        );
  }
```

Interface:

```
export interface APIResponse {
    data
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this,

```
 ngOnInit() {
        this.api.getRecipeIndex()
            .subscribe(resp=>{    
               this.recipes = resp;
               });
            }
```